# C++ pointers under windows 7

Tags: c++

whenever a value is assigned to any pointer variable that is not working under windows 7 (32 bit) environment. Program containing such a code are getting execution error.
Actually I was trying to concatenate two strings without using any library functions.
Example:

```
   int main()
   {
       char *s1 = "Hello";
       char *s2 = "World";
       char *p;
       p = s1;

       while(*s1 != '\0')
          s1++;

       while(*s2 != '\0')
       {
           *s1 = *s2;  // this line creating problem
           s1++;
           s2++;
       }
       *s1 = '\0';  // this line also creating problem

       while(*p != '\0')
       {
           cout<<*p;
           p++;
       }


       return 0;

    }
```

Comment: **Never** use a non-const `char *` to point to a string literal.

Comment: Is this really C++? `char *s1 = "Hello";` shan't even compile. (Nor should `while (...) <br />`... >.< )

Comment: @H2CO3, Could still be pre-C++11. It's only deprecated there. In any case, AFAIK, compilers still accept it in C++11 for whatever reason.

Comment: @H2CO3 This compiles fine. Only the assignment to `*s1` is a problem.

Comment: @chris and Harper: OMG that's a disaster. But why? AFAIK in C++, string literals have type `const char[N + 1]`. The lack of `const`-ness is a quirk of C, not of C++... or is it?

Comment: @H2CO3, And C++ likes to be compatible with C a bit too much sometimes. Thankfully, they realized this was a mistake. Yes, though, they are an array of *const* characters in C++.

Comment: @chris Well, maybe C++ tries too hard, but it doesn't succeed in being C-compatible very well... (which is sometimes good, sometimes bad. Anyway this is getting OT :/)

Answer (score 4):

You have not allocated space to write into -- that's why you're having a problem.

You've created `s1` and pointed it at some read-only memory, and when you try to append, you're then writing into that region.

You could instead set `p` to point to some memory that a) you own (have the right to write into, not just the physical ability) and b) is large enough for the full allocation.

Your easiest way to do this will be instead to use `std::string` -- after all, you say you're using C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s1 = "Hello";
char *s2 = "World";
```

When you create s1 and s2 like this, you can't write:

```
*s2 = anything;
```

Because of string pooling `s1` and `s2` are immutable by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s1 = "Hello";
```

Here, `"Hello"` is a string literal, which is by definition `const`.  `s1` is a pointer to the first element of that string literal, and so points to read-only memory.  You cannot change read-only memory, and so you can't change what is pointed to by`s1`.  It would have been much more accrate and better if you had declared this as:

```
const char *s1 = "Hello";
```

In C++03, there is a special rule which allows assigning the pointer to a string literal to a non-`const` pointer.  However that rule was removed in C++11, and your code is actually illegal now.

This is a good thing because even in C++03 there is nothing you can (legally) do with `s1` that you couldn't do if it was `const`.

Later, you do something patently wrong:

```
 while(*s2 != '\0')
       {
           *s1 = *s2;  // this line creating problem
           s1++;
           s2++;
       }
```

I'm not surprised that line of code is causing a problem for you -- it evokes Undefined Behavior because you are modifying read-only memory.

It looks like what you're really trying to do is create a string which is initialized with some known (unchanging) value, and then later modify the string.  In order to do that, you must make a copy of the string literal.  Easiest way to do that is to use `std::string`:

```
std::string s1 = "Hello";
```

Here `"Hello"` is still a string literal, but `s1` is being constructed off of it.  `s1` is completely separate from the string literal, and now you can modify it however you wish.